# gzip compression using mod_deflate apache with tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, compression, mod-deflate

I'm trying to enable gzip compression in my Apache server which is fronting a Tomcat instance using a connector. I tried several variants of the module configuration settings in my httpd.conf. Here is my latest attempt:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

DeflateCompressionLevel 9
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$ no-gzip dont-vary
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
DeflateFilterNote Input instream
DeflateFilterNote Output outstream
DeflateFilterNote Ratio ratio

LogFormat '"%r" %{outstream}n/%{instream}n (%{ratio}n%%)' deflate
CustomLog "/var/output/logs/deflate_log" deflate
ErrorLog "/var/output/logs/deflate_error_log"
</IfModule>
```

I'm checking the response headers using Firebug and I verified that the request headers have `Accept-Encoding: gzip deflate` but every time, the `Content-Encoding` header is missing from response.

I tried adding the following line to `httpd.conf`, but it is giving an error that `mod_deflate` is a built-in module and cannot be loaded. I confirmed this by `apachectl -t` and it shows `mod_deflate.c` as compiled module.

```
LoadModule deflate_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
```

I've a Tomcat instance that is connected to Apache via AJP connector. When I debugged my servlets, I found that the response `Content-Type` I'm getting for my test script is `application/javascript;charset=UTF-8`. I initially was using `AddOutputFilterByType` directive and thought that the additional `charset=UTF-8` part might be messing up the MIME type for Apache, but then it isn't working with `SetOutputFilter DEFLATE` also.

My custom logs for `deflate` show the following line repeatedly:

```
GET /myservlet HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
```

I don't understand why this isn't working. My Apache version is `2.0.63`. Did anybody face similar issue? Is there anyway I can debug further and check what is going on within Apache? Perhaps enabling some debug logging?

Thanks,
Venkat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable compression on Tomcat not on httpd for content served by Tomcat.

Comment: According to this post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653642/tomcat-7-gzip-compression-not-working), it seems if Tomcat is fronted by Apache, we need to do it on Apache and not Tomcat. I tried enabling compression on Tomcat, but it isn't working either.

Comment: As an additional note, Tomcat is compressing data if I access it directly on its own port 8080. But when I go through Apache, it is not compressing the data.