# Compression of Tomcat mod_jk results in Apache httpd

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-jk, compression, servlet

I'm developing a web application locally on my system, serving it using Tomcat (tomcat-7.0.52).
In production, I want to front the Tomcat with an Apache httpd (Apache/2.2.15).

This works and I managed to configure caching as needed.
Now I want to configure compression, but it seems that a can't get Apache httpd to modify the response it got from Tomcat.

But as I read here, this is the preferred way of doing to. mod_jk compression is only between httpd and Tomcat and if I want to configure compression directly in Tomcat, I'd need an extra servlet for it.

I have the following line in my vhost-file to enable compression of static and httpd-served content:

```
 #SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html application/json text/xml text/css text/javascript
```

Enabling the 1st line didn't change anything for me.

I pass these requests to Tomcat using mod_jk:

```
<IfModule mod_jk.c>
 JkMount /myapp/j_security_check worker1
 JkMount /myapp/*.jsp worker1
 JkMount /myapp/DataSourceLoader worker1
 JkMount /myapp/ServletLogin worker1
</IfModule>
```

Using Firebug I can see that the mime-type of the Tomcat-returned requests is

```
/myapp/j_security_check: "text/plain; charset=UTF-8" (with the space)
/myapp/*.jsp: "text/plain; charset=UTF-8" (with the space)
/myapp/DataSourceLoader: "application/json;charset=UTF-8"  (without space)
```

Because of the spaces I can't add to **AddOutputFilterByType** and as I also have the mime-types without the UTF-8 and I also tried with just **SetOutputFilter**, I think that these directives do not manipulate the Tomcat answer at all.

So my questions are:

1. What's the best suggested solution? Tomcat compression or Apache
   httpd compression? (According to [gzip compression using mod_deflate apache with tomcat](https://serverfault.com/questions/582666/gzip-compression-using-mod-deflate-apache-with-tomcat?rq=1#comment683042_582708) (which redirects here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653642/tomcat-7-gzip-compression-not-working) it should be done in httpd)
2. **How do I enable Apache httpd-compression for mod_jk results** (perhaps
   from JBoss and not Tomcat)?
3. Perhaps related: **How do I modify caching headers from mod_jk results
   in Apache httpd?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Blama,

I agree with #1 in that compression can be handled with apache or another web server.

Here are my thoughts:

1. I use apache mod_proxy or nginx in front of tomcat. This allows me to handle SSL, compression and static content if needed. I have started to move to nginx to replace apache on the front end.
2. mod_deflate for apache or nginx ngx_http_gzip_module
3. You can handle all the caching rules in tomcat or apache. It depends on what rules you want.